# Satellizer login JWT token is gone when page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwt, satellizer

[image]

I am using the [`Angular-satellizer`](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) extension for the login/register feature but I am stuck at number 7.

Token was saved to `localStorage` but I when refresh the page it's gone and `$auth.isAuthenticated()` function is returning false.

[image]

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $state, $auth, jwtHelper) {
  $scope.login = function() {
    $auth.login($scope.user)
      .then(function(response) {
        var gelenToken = response.data;
        var tokenPayload = jwtHelper.decodeToken(gelenToken.token);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(tokenPayload)); // Output:{"sub":"1","iat":1496346513,"exp":1497556113,"data":{"role":"admin"}}
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(tokenPayload));
        $state.go('baba.manga');
      })
  };
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this :

> localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);

OR

> $window.localStorage.token = JSON.stringify(data.token);

to save your token, You can see the token in browser local Storage, You don't need to decode that token unless you need it to.

It should not get deleted on page refresh, If its getting deleted the I suggest you to try breakpoints at places and debug which part is clearing local storage.

Browser does not delete any localstorage data at any point, Your code might be doing it.

Comment: Satellizer manuel says `Parse the token and save it to localStorage`. Parse mean decode right?

Comment: I don't think so, parse means extract and save, not decode,you have to send encoded token to server not decoded.

Comment: Ok. I find the issue. token only saved for `login.html` not for all pages. Now I need to share the token with `index.html` or `$scope.isAuthenticated = function()` share this function with `index.html`'s state. Which is better?

Comment: Satellizer has its own function `$auth.setToken(token)` and this saves the token for the all pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you refresh the page , you are reseting the localStorage and your last token gone.

Try this

```
// if the localScore is not set then initialize it 
if(localStorage.getItem('token') === null) {
     localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(tokenPayload));
}
```